# CNN Keras model.fit and model.fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I had tried model.fit() and model.fit_generator() but the result show that the model.fit() has better result compared to model.fit_generator(). I would like to augment the training set thus I used ImageDataGenerator() and model.fit_generator(). Below is the graph with model.fit() and model.fit_generator(). 
[image]

As you can see, the model.fit() has a better validation accuracy and validation loss compared to model.fit_generator(). Below is my CNN code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=2)

model = Sequential()

# filters, kernel size, input size
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=X.shape[1:], padding='Same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='Same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='Same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="CNN_Model_Rebuilt/logs/{}".format(NAME))
augmented_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    'CNN_Model_Rebuilt/best model/' + NAME + '-best.h5',
    monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
    save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                   min_delta=0,
                   patience=20,
                   verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    zoom_range=0.1,  # Randomly zoom image
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images

datagen.fit(X_train)

epochs = 50
batchsize = 16

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=batchsize),
                              epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, to_categorical(y_test)),
                              verbose=2, steps_per_epoch=X-train.shape[0], callbacks= 
                              [augmented_checkpoint, tensorboard, es])
```

Does the code any problem? Any suggestion will be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They should give the same results on the same data. I notice in your code you have
datagen.fit(X_train). You don't need this since you have  featurewise_center=False, samplewise_center=False, featurewise_std_normalization=False, featureewise_std_normalization=False,and zca_whitening=False. You show your code for model.fit_generator but not for model.fit. Did you use the same data generator to provide the input to model.fit? Your generator is augmenting the data so the training data gets modified by the generator. If you do not have the same data for both model.fit and model.fit_generator  you will get different results. Also note that the parameters in model.fit and model.fit_generator are not identical. Make sure you are selecting the training and validation data in the same manner for both cases. Also did you use flow from directory? Did you set the batch size in flow from directory with the fit generator to be the same as the batch size for model.fit.